# IntelliJ throws java.lang.IllegalStateException on decompilation of .kt file

Tags: java, kotlin, converters

I am trying to decompile a file from Kotlin to Java, but when I am using the Show Kotlin Bytecode option, it just throws java.lang.IllegalStateException, I sadly can't show the file, but I have to add that the file has some errors  I haven't been able to fix yet.

Comment: The JVM-byte-code of Kotlin may or may not be fully compatible for Java language, afterall Kotlin != Java, it may use some different kind of approach for optimization so there might be errors in decompiled code (of kotlin in java).

Comment: maybe provide the exception trace to help understand what has gone wrong

Comment: File a bug report at Kotlin's YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT. See if you can manually obfuscate your code file, removing all sensitive information, and attach it to the report - that should help the Kotlin team find the root cause.